# If statement not acting how it should do

Tags: php, if-statement

In a project i am currently doing it involves using an if statement that sends an email if a condition equals 1. The issue with the statement is that although it sends email it sends three then waits then sends another three.

The waiting is what i want but i cant wrap my head round why it is sending three and just one email at a time.

```
function get_num_clients()
{
    $wlan0_clients = exec('iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep Station | wc -l');

    if($wlan0_clients == "1"){


        exec('arp -n');
        sleep(5);
        exec('cat /proc/net/arp > /pineapple/email_log.txt');
        sleep(5);
        exec('/pineapple/emailbash.sh');
        sleep(5);
        exec('> /pineapple/email_log.txt');
        sleep(285);

    }

}
```

This is the statement that i have and the bash script just has the code to send the email. Any help would be great.

Mark

Comment: Have you verified the value of `$wlan0_clients`? That seems like the most obvious first step in debugging this.

Comment: what's in emailbash? What email sending method do you use? Maybe there is some sort of limit to how many emails can be processed and sent in parallel and that causes the bottleneck. Hardly an if and php problem.

Comment: `wc -l` will have leading spaces in the output, try trimming the output, or most importantly, do what John said.